# Sum of all the values of a field in Kibana using elasticsearch query DSL

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have seen quite a few similar questions answered but they are all for older versions of Kibana, or do not actually help with my particular question.

I want to find the sum of all values in a specific field,the kibana docs give the following example code for creating the sum of a field.

```
POST /sales/_search?size=0
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "match" : { "type" : "hat" }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "hat_prices" : { "sum" : { "field" : "price" } }
    }
}
```

Based on this, the following should sum all the values in the field "tweetSentiment.polarity"
(POST /sales/_search?size=0 was removed because the UI gives an "unexpected 'p'" error with that line in.)

```
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "match" : { "type" : "number" }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "hat_prices" : { "sum" : { "field" : "tweetSentiment.polarity" } }
    }
}
```

Changing around the values for "type" and "field" between all the possible combinations of things they could be did not solve the issue either. My best guess is that this is not actually the code I want, especially after digging deep into how to create the query I am looking for.

Comment: I think it must be related to the dot in ur field , tweetSentiment.polarity , can u try with some field that has no dot in its name

Comment: You should probably show your mapping (especially for `tweetSentiment.polarity`)  as well as a sample document.